# Teamasys skylink-webrtc web integration for audio and vedio call console issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, webrtc

I am using Temasys skylink webrtc plugin and implemented screen share functionality  in Temasys console by creating app and its generating app key and secret key.Implemented screen share functionality by using app-key with in javascript code its working fine for local.Now i am getting issue in video call and audio call functionality in console its shows error no meeting preschedule for this static key.

[image: Console Error]

[image: App console details]

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.dev.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.temasys.com.sg/adapterjs/0.11.x/adapter.debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.temasys.io/skylink/skylinkjs/0.6.31/skylink.min.js"></script>
<video id="localVideo" autoplay="autoplay"></video>
<div id="peerVideoList"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="joinRoom()">Start Call</button>
<button type="button" onclick="leaveRoom()">End Call</button>
<script>
var sl = new Skylink();

sl.init('3d97e1b5-ed80-4dbc-b395-4dc17c6880c9');

// A new Peer has joined the Room
sl.on('peerJoined', function(peerId, peerInfo){
  console.log('Peer ' + peerId + ' has joined the room');
  var peerVideo = document.createElement('video');
  peerVideo.id = peerId + '_video';
  peerVideo.autoplay = 'autoplay';
  document.getElementById('peerVideoList').appendChild(peerVideo);
});
// Peer has Audio/Video stream to add
sl.on('addPeerStream', function(peerId, stream){
  // attachMediaStream is a Adapter function
  attachMediaStream(document.getElementById(peerId + '_video'), stream);
});
// User's Audio/Video stream has been successfully added
sl.on('mediaAccessSuccess', function(stream){
  // attachMediaStream is a Adapter function
  attachMediaStream( document.getElementById('localVideo'), stream );
});
// A Peer has left the room
sl.on('peerLeft', function(peerId){
  var peer = document.getElementById(peerId + '_video');
  document.getElementById('peerVideoList').removeChild(peer);
}); 

function joinRoom () { sl.joinRoom({ audio : true, video : true }); }
function leaveRoom () { sl.leaveRoom(); } 


</script>
```